# What is the meaning of taking hash for consistent train-test set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, hash

I am a total newbie of machine learning and currently try to understand the meaning behind the action in the book.The author splited the test and train set,but then he wanted to fix the problem of new test set everytime we run the programm.

> A common  solution    is  to  use each    instance’s  identifier  to  decide  whether or  not it  should  go  in  the test    set (assuming   instances   have    a unique    and immutable   identifier).    For example,    you could   compute a   hash    of  each    instance’s  identifier, keep    only    the last    byte    of  the hash,   and put the instance    in  the test    set if  this    value   is  lower   or  equal   to  51 (~20%    of  256).   This    ensures that    the test    set will    remain  consistent  across  multiple    runs,   even    if  you refresh the dataset.    The new test    set will    contain 20% of  the new instances,  but it  will    not contain any instance    that    was previously  in  the training    set.    Here    is  a   possible    implementation:

This whole expanation is confusing to me.
I don't understand why do we even take the hash in the first place.And secondly,what does the line about 20% new instances even mean?We have a new data,how will it even can it contain the instances of the previous training set?Or is the training left intact even when refreshing the data and we update only the test set?
Does taking the values that are lower than 51 allows us to set the test set randomly,but the same through the repeated running of the code?

Here is the code for more clarity:

```
def split_train_test(data, ratio):
    random_indeces = np.random.permutation(len(data))
    test_index = int(len(data) * ratio)
    train_data = random_indeces[test_index:]
    test_data = random_indeces[:test_index]
    return data.iloc[train_data], data.iloc[test_data]
train_set, test_set = split_train_test(housing, 0.2)


def test_set_check(identifier, test_ratio, hash): 
    return hash(np.int64(identifier)).digest()[-1] < 256 * test ratio


def split_train_test_by_id(data, test_ration, id_column, hash=hashlib.md5):
    ids = data[id_column]
    in_test_set = ids.apply(lambda id_: test_set_check(id_, test_ratio, hash))
    return data.loc[~in_test_set], data.loc[in_test_set]
housing_with_id = housing.reset_index()
train_set, test_set = split_train_test_by_id(housing_with_id, 0.2, 'index')
```

I tried seeking information in the inthernet,but to no avail.Hope you to help me understand,don't want to leave blank spaces in knowledge.

Comment: The author of the book has posted a [detailed explanation](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/issues/71#issuecomment-323021995) of the said method of using a hash function to split data into train and test sets.

Answer (score 0):

Hash number is taken to turn all ID in a same fixed lenght. Once we achieve this, we keep only the last byte (8 bits, 2**8=256 values) of each hash number, so you have randomly mapped  all instances in these 256 values. If we take those hash that are between 0 and 51, we are randomly taking the 20% of the data. New instances are also randomly mapped into these 8 bits, so if we add 'x' new instances, 20% of them will fall between 0 and 51, and you can assume that your test set is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute a hash of each instance's identifier and put that instance in the test set if the hash is lower than or equal to 20% of the maximum hash value. This ensures that the test set will remain consistent across multiple runs, even if you refresh the new dataset. The new test set will contain 20% of the new instances, but it will not contain any instance that was previously in the training set.